# Convert a time to nanoseconds in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time, nanotime

I have the following time format:

```
require 'time'

input = "2016-10-04_00.50.31.147"
format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S.%N"

time = Time.strptime(input, format)
```

How do I get the number of nanoseconds since the epoch?

Comment: Your time seems to be wrong. Somehow, `147` is interpreted as milliseconds, not nanoseconds.

Comment: @sawa `%N` parses fractional seconds, i.e. `147` is interpreted as 0.147 seconds.

Comment: @marco what's your expected result?

Comment: @Stefan That is what I am pointing out. And I think the OP intended that part to be interpreted as nanoseconds since the documentation says `%N` is defaulted to the 9th decimal place.

Answer (score 4):

This should give you the value:

```
time.to_f * (10 ** 9)
```

If you want an integer, apply `to_i` or whatever to it.

However, notice that your `time` is wrong, so it would not give the right results.

Comment: Or `time.to_i * (10 ** 9) + time.nsec` to avoid floating point errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://apidock.com/ruby/Time/nsec

```rb
t = Time.now        #=> 2007-11-17 15:18:03 +0900
"%10.9f" % t.to_f   #=> "1195280283.536151409"
t.nsec              #=> 536151406
```